# CXF tomcat 8 weblogic java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, cxf, code-first, jaxb2

I am actuallay work on a projet based on spring 3.2.8 and cxf 2.7.11 and run on weblogic 12.1 (JDK 1.7.0_21) and tomcat 8.
Webservices are code in code first with CXF annotations.

When I try to run my web app on weblogic or on Tomcat, I get this exception :

`Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.Map
        at private java.util.Map fr.grdf.distribution.ws.interfaces.metier.approvisionnement.jaxws_asm.GetEotpCodeArticleByZddResponse._return
        at fr.grdf.distribution.ws.interfaces.metier.approvisionnement.jaxws_asm.GetEotpCodeArticleByZddResponse`

On weblogic, I just have to configure the classpath with thoses lines in weblogic.xml configuration file and everything works fine :

`<prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.apache.cxf.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>`

But on tomcat, I am stuck on this error. The only difference in classpath between tomcat webapp and weblogic webapp is the add of asm-3.3.1.jar for tomcat (I get a  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError": org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter execption)

Is anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Webservice end point :

```
@WebService
@GZIP
public interface IApproLogWebService {
@WebMethod
Map<Long, String> getEotpCodeArticleByZdd(@WebParam(name = "articles") List<ArticleFicheApproLog> articles,
    @WebParam(name = "zdd") Zdd zdd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by upgrading jabx-xjc from 2.2.1.1 version to 2.2.10-b140310.1920 version.

Regards.